# Do CSS files get sent to browser?

Tags: html, css

Do **CSS** files get sent to brower for the browser to render the page, or are **CSS** files processed server side, with only the **HTML** page being sent to browser?

Comment: They are sent to the browser and processed by the browser.

Comment: To be really nitpicky, they are fetched by the browser, rather than sent by the server...

Comment: @Benjol: The browser sends a request to the server, the server *sends* the CSS to the browser in response ;)

Comment: @Niels: well, the browser doesn’t *have* to send a request to the server for the CSS files. Internet Explorer will request the HTML file, then request any CSS files linked to by the HTML file, but Lynx (the text-only browser on Unix) will request the HTML file and refrain from requesting any CSS files mentioned in it. Thus the server will never send them.

Comment: @Paul: Hey, I did say 'in response', so yes, in the case of Lynx there won't be anything to respond to :)

Comment: @Niels: oh totally, I just thought there was a tiny chance of confusion regarding what was being responded to. Theoretically, someone might think that when servers get a request for an HTML page, they send back the HTML page and any associated CSS files in the same response.

Comment: @Paul: You're absolutely right, I didn't think of it that way. Thanks for clearing it up!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are sent to browsers, along with JS files and other resources referenced in your HTML page. Of course, browser may never actually request these files (for example, if you disabled images display), but nothing gets applied server-side.

Answer (score 7):

CSS is processed client-side by the browser. So yes, it is downloaded by the browser along with HTML, images, Javascript etc.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the CSS file is sent to the browser to render the page.

This image will help you to understand, where the CSS file gets downloaded to the client browser.

[alt text http://www.lokalisointi.org/~magi/itmill/book/polish/book-pl/img/intro/firebug.png](http://www.lokalisointi.org/~magi/itmill/book/polish/book-pl/img/intro/firebug.png)

You can use Firefox and the [Firebug plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) to check this.

Answer (score 2):

CSS files are sent to the browser as well (unless they are already cached client side)

Answer (score 1):

CSS is processed by the browser, client-side.

Answer (score 1):

Css behaves like html files, they get fetched by the browser and then the browser does all the rendering. 
The same thing happens with image files and javascript. That is why you have different behaviors for different browsers, each browser interprets the css files as they want and that's why you have to tune up your css files for IE, Firefox, chrome, opera, etc...

The best way to make your css files work in almost all the browsers (apart from IE6) is writing the css file using the w3c standards, Firefox, Chrome, opera and IE9 are supposed to be W3cCompliant.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is sent to the browser what is *supposed to design your page* including CSS, HTML, Javascript.